# MongoDB java driver: can't find jar that contains org.bson.types.ObjectId

Tags: java, mongodb

I just can't find the jar file that contains the class org.bson.types.ObjectId

First, I made sure I had the correct object and package name correct:
http://api.mongodb.com/java/3.1/org/bson/types/ObjectId.html

...so, org.bson.types.ObjectId is the correct package+class name...

I downloaded a couple of versions [3.0.0, 3.1.0, 3.2.0, 3.2.2, 3.3.0] from here:
https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/mongodb/mongodb-driver/

I explode them (unzip them) and I can see that the jars do contain a package org.bson.types but there is no ObjectId class in there (!!!).

IMPORTANT: The MondoDB page says that the BSON library is included in the mongo java driver so it should all be there I'd think; I should not have to download the bson library separately, right? See here:
http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/

I have a feeling I'll smack my forehead when someone tells me the answer (or maybe not).... Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arg, doh! I'll delete this question. This old project is using ANT and the MongoDB POM shows the dependencies I was missing. See: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/mongodb/mongodb-driver/3.3.0/mongodb-driver-3.3.0.pom

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
<artifactId>bson</artifactId>
<version>3.3.0</version>
<scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

And those BSON missing classes are in the dependency here:
https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/mongodb/bson/3.3.0/

Argg, this is why I should switch old projects from ANT to GRADLE when I revisit them. Or at least Maven... DOH!

Answer (score 0):

ObjectId class is available in the bson-3.0.1.jar , you can download the same at http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/b/Downloadbson301jar.htm

Comment: Yes, I was tempted to download it separately but MongoDB java driver says that BSON is included in the Mongo java driver (indeed it is included, it's just missing some important classes like ObjectId). I added a note on the question above. Adding a separate jar that also contains BSON might lead to clashes because the mongo jar (that contains BSON) and the other jar that would contain some of the same classes but from different jar versions, leading to a lot of aches and pain.